# Add two different variable types into a dictionary for multiple custom headers for a GET request

Tags: c#, api, dictionary

I have the following two headers I need to add to a GET request

```
 string firstHeader = "dksflkjdfjk";
 DateTime secondHeader = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

I then want to add them both to a dictionary but they are different variable types

I have done this so far

```
  Dictionary<string, string> customHeaders = new Dictionary<string, object>();
  customHeaders.Add("FirstHeader", firstHeader );
  customHeaders.Add("SecondHeader", secondHeader);
```

But I get an error

```
  CS0029 Cannoth Implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>'
```

My question is how to get the dictionary to accept two different variable types?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn´t put **different** things into the **same** collection. While you *could* do that, it´s seldomly a good idea.

Comment: why not convert your `DateTime` to `string`: `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()` for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to assign a `Dictionary<string, object>` to a `Dictionary<string, string>` which are obviously incompatible types.

Change your code to:

```
Dictionary<string, object> customHeaders = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

or even better:

```
var customHeaders = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

That solves the type casting problem. Furthermore, HTTP Headers are always strings so I am not sure why you want to store different types at all. This is valid for **HTTP/2** as well.

Comment: @HimBromBeere While I agree, he might have a use of it. He would need to cast the header values to strings at the end anyway, so I am not sure what's the actual use of this dictionary at all but we're lacking context.

Comment: tried both of these solutions, thanks, but I still get the error        CS1503 Argument 4: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, string>'

Comment: @RShome This is impossible. You're having an error in your code for sure. Here is a working fiddle with the above solution: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wJXIir.

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks, yes there was an error in my code oops. My header title was case-senstivie and I got one of the letters wrong. Sorry for taking up your time.